# React MUI 5 timepicker mask will not work unless ampm prop is = false and it would only work w/ hh:mm format

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker, masking

Using MUI-5 time picker for our React app and are trying to implement mask for keyboard input. However, the only way for mask to work is when the ampm prop is false and only seem to work for hh:mm

Here is the only code I can make the mask to work

```
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DateAdapterLuxon}>
      <Stack spacing={3}>
        <TimePicker
          value={value}
          onChange={setValue}
          inputFormat="hh:mm"
          ampm={false}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </Stack>
    </LocalizationProvider>
```

if I remove `ampm={false}` (the default is true) then masking will not work.
even with `ampm={false}` it will not accept custom mask or if `inputFormat` is anything other then `hh:mm`

Comment: You may want to check the material-ui issues for this: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+TimePicker+mask looks like the issue is known.

Comment: yeah, looks like it's a know issue w/ no fix in sigh... :(